# Expect command output to be stored in a variable

Tags: expect

I have written below script .

---

```
#! /usr/bin/expect
set timeout 180
spawn /vobs/iov/rnc/bin/moshell/moshell -d db.dat
expect {
  -re "OFFLINE_DB.DAT.*" { }
        timeout        { 
     error "\n######## Timeout - when logging in\n"
 }
        eof            { 
     error "\n######## eof - when logging in\n"
 } 
}

set db_prompt "SQL>"
send "select id from motype_r1 where data = 'PlugInUnit';\r"
expect {
  -re "OFFLINE_DB.DAT>"  
}    
 exit
```

---

Now , I want to get the output of the table in a variable i.e

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|   19 |
+------+
Query Done: 1 record selected
```

and match regular expression to get '19' in one more varible.

Can anybody please help me with the solution.

/Akshya

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use code tag to format your code sample and add more information to the question. Also add relevant tags to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

In this block of code, you should be able to use a the regex to match the output of the SELECT query, then store it in a variable.

```
send "select id from motype_r1 where data = 'PlugInUnit';\r"
expect {
  -re {(\|[^\d]*(\d+).*\|)} { set id $expect_out(1,string) ; exp_continue }
  -re "OFFLINE_DB.DAT>"  
}
```

(Pardon the somewhat ugly regexp that I used, but it should match the last numerical id in the return statement.)

The `$expect_out(1,string)` refers to the first string match in the regex, then the exp_continue will cause expect to continue expecting output until it sees the "OFFLINE_DB.DAT" message (which I don't think needs the `-re` prefix, by the way).

Hope that works!